# How to handle DynamoDB Global streams

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Looking to create a DynamoDB global table for storing customer information. The problem I have is my current pattern is to listen to changes on this table and send email updates using Lambda triggers.

i.e. Your profile information was changed. If this was not you..

Do I now need to have that Lambda in each region and will data replication mean that it is triggered for each region?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you might have misunderstood with streams.

Global Tables needs **streams enabled on the table to replicate** between regions. You can check the requirements and how it works.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/globaltables_HowItWorks.html

If you have trigger, you can have only in one region. Whichever region is having the lambda associated to the trigger will get notified with the updates.

The benefit from the global table you get is, if any regions updates the data, the lambda in the region you have configured will get triggered. Only one trigger will be sent to the lambda.

**Enabling streams is one of the requirements for DynamoDB Global Tables.**

If you create trigger in multiple regions, you need to implement your Lambda with idempotency i.e., if the same data is delivered any number of times, it will perform the operation only once.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please clarify "if any regions updates the data, the lambda in the region you have configured will get triggered", does this mean if table in region A updates the data, trigger in region B won't receive it?

Comment: It will receive it. Lambda is associated with its region.

Comment: what this means is you have to make sure triggers AKA lambda performs idempotent operations. Write happened in Region A, will trigger Lambda A, great, but when Region B gets the replication, Lambda B should have some smartness to ignore the operation. You can have write_region in the document to lock which region gets to act on the trigger.

Comment: idempotent, if you receive the same event twice, then you should keep the resulting processed data the same.  Idempotent - denoting an element of a set which is unchanged in value when multiplied or otherwise operated on by itself.

Comment: Thanks @Kannaiyan spot on. I was deploying a similar stack to all regions so the change was to split out the infra as code for the tables from the infra as code for the lambda which gets deployed to the master region only for me.